# How does the script /etc/init.d/sudo work?

Tags: sudo, init.d, privileges, etc

I was reading the script `/etc/init.d/sudo`. It has been written as a comment in the script that it **provides limited super user privileges to specific users**.

Though, I could not understand the script as to how is it working?
Can someone explain me the script?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

Answer (score 5):

init files, which run at system boot (or on demand) do two main things:

- they start daemons running
- they do various one-time-per-boot tasks, such as cleaning up or preparing files, setting network parameters, etc.

In this case, the `sudo` init script does not start a daemon. Instead, it invalidates any cached credential files that may have been left around when the system last shut down. It does this by using `touch` to set their modification time to a very long time ago (0, which is Jan 1, 1970).

```
case "$1" in
  start)
        # make sure privileges don't persist across reboots
        if [ -d /var/lib/sudo ]
        then
                find /var/lib/sudo -exec touch -d @0 '{}' \;
        fi
        ;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts in `/etc/init.d` are there to allow the starting and stopping of services by [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) and similar init systems. They have a specific format and are what is actually called when you do something like

```
service sudo stop
```

So, the script you mention is simply a wrapper that can start or stop the `sudo` service. For more details, I suggest you read up on Linux init scripts.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the sudo mechanism as opposed to init.d scripts.

Comment: @Ketan I suspect so too but that's not what the actual question is saying.

Comment: The sudo daemon??? Where did you find that beast?

Comment: @guntbert 'tis in a land far away and lost in time and only the bravest of knights may find it. It has also been removed from this answer.

Comment: ah good - I was really scared at the thought having lived next to it for a long time and having it frequently but inadvertently invoked :-)